# datstax cassandra setup guide

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, datastax

Would like to know if any setup guides available for capacity planning for Datastax Cassandra. If there is any real world use case available for hardware and software requirements for utilizing the complete Datastax stack with DR and failover settings, bandwidth requirements, would be more useful. I found the recommendations in Datstax documentation but wondering if that would suffice.

Comment: Check out these links http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware and http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/WP-DataStax-Enterprise-Best-Practices.pdf

Comment: thanks @phact, I read the guide from Datastax, it is useful but if anyone could put their learnings on the setup part it will be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try Cassandra stress test on your system, based on output you can calculate the hardware requirements.
Output example for single node:

```
Cassandra Performance on 1 Node Cluster Write operation:

Results:
op rate                   : 6636
partition rate            : 6636
row rate                  : 6636
latency mean              : 30.1
latency median            : 25.9
latency 95th percentile   : 65.6
latency 99th percentile   : 94.3
latency 99.9th percentile : 140.9
latency max               : 1381.2
total gc count            : 150
total gc mb               : 22123
total gc time (s)         : 8
avg gc time(ms)           : 51
stdev gc time(ms)         : 12
Total operation time      : 00:02:30
END
```